# queryMySQL.php?query=myquery returns 403 forbidden error sometime

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have created a web site where in one page I select search criteria for mysql.
Depending on the drop-down elements selected, I create a string that I call myquery in a javascript, then I use

```
window.location.href = "queryMySQL.php?query=" + myquery;
```

and call a different page.

This works sometimes, but sometimes it gives me the 403 error and the page shows:

> You don't have permission to access queryMySQL.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I cannot figure out why it works sometimes and sometimes it does not, the syntax of the query is not a problem, I can get this error even if I remove the code on the page.

Additionally, this worked fine on another web hosting site, but when I copied this implementation on a different site I started having problems.

Suggestions?

EDIT **********************************************************

As I said this has nothing to do with the query. The target page can be a blank html page, and the error is still there. It looks like some security issue on this web hosting site because it worked fine on the other one and on my own server.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the code, but my guess is that you need to call `encodeURIComponent(myquery)` so that special characters in the query will be encoded properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
window.location.href = "queryMySQL.php?query=" + encodeURIComponent(myquery);
```

The query probably contains special characters that need to be encoded in a URL.

Comment: Have you checked the server log?

Comment: Also check the Network tab in Developer Tools, to see the actual URL it's trying to load.

Comment: I am uploading the files on host-ed.net, and I am not sure how to check those things there. On my own server it works fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, without those details it's almost impossible to troubleshoot. Contact the hosting service and find out how to view your logs.